# setInterval 0 does not work in IE8

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a method `changeColor` that updates the CSS on some elements in my HTML.
I also have a timer that controls this being applied i.e:

```
var timer = setInterval(changeColor,0);
```

The problem i'm facing is using that time interval of 0 results in the changeColor method not being run, however if i change it something minimal like:

```
var timer = setInterval(changeCalendarColor,1);
```

it works.

Now i'd be happy to use this however in IE8 this causes a slight delay in the colors appearing.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Thanks.

Comment: 1 millisecond causes delay.

Comment: What did you expect to happen when you set the time of 0 for an interval?

Comment: Your first example is `changeColor`, your second is `changeCalendarColor`. Is that a typo? Or are you actually calling two different methods? If the later, how do you know `changeColor` would work if the delay was non-zero?

Comment: @Huangism: I assume they expected the function to execute.

Comment: @MattBurland see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648557/setinterval-behaviour-with-0-milliseconds-in-javascript

Comment: @MattBurland yes thats a typo

Comment: @Huangism I'm hoping that the CSS styling would appear straight away

Comment: @Satpal yes I'm aware but if i use 0 the styling does not appear at all

Comment: Shouldn't you be using setTimeout anyway?

Comment: @userMod2 are you getting a js error when you use 0? Seems fine here http://jsfiddle.net/Rk4pj/

Comment: @Huangism no error and that fiddle works fine in FIrefox, but cannot load in IE8.

Comment: Could we please see the function you're calling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The `setInterval` function takes a function to call and a delay in milliseconds. You cannot have a delay of 0 milliseconds; there is a minimum delay in place** (which according to the [specs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout#Minimum_delay_and_timeout_nesting) is 4ms). Take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval) for more.

```
// To call a function every second:
var timer = setInterval(myFunction, 1000); 

// This doesn't throw an error as the 0 is being overridden by a default minimum:
var timer = setInterval(myFunction, 0);
```

If you want to call the function initially and ALSO every second after that, you should call the function when you set the interval:

```
var timer = setInterval(myFunction, 1000); 
myFunction();
```

---

Here's what the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout#Minimum_delay_and_timeout_nesting) say about **the minimum delay**:

*"In fact, 4ms is specified by the HTML5 spec and is consistent across browsers released in 2010 and onward. Prior to (Firefox 5.0 / Thunderbird 5.0 / SeaMonkey 2.2), the minimum timeout value for nested timeouts was 10 ms."*

---

Regarding the slowness on IE8, **the setInterval "lag" is probably being caused by IE8 being too slow to keep up with what the function is trying to do**. At each time interval, the function is called, but IE8 is queue is being overloaded as a result -- to the point that IE8 can't keep up. Increasing the delay would mask this issue I'd imagine.

As Vasile says on [this Google Code forum](https://code.google.com/p/jsc3d/issues/detail?id=7):

*"When a new call is triggered if the previous call is not ended then the new call is queued  and will wait for it's time to be executed; and here is the problem... (the timer will slow down when the queue will grow and the performance will go down over time)"*

Note that this is a common problem for low delays in IE8; [check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941364/setinterval-slugish-in-ie-8-at-50-times-a-second) for more on this specific issue.

---

Also, a quick point to note about setInterval delays is that **inactive tabs are occasionally treated differently**:

*"In (Firefox 5.0 / Thunderbird 5.0 / SeaMonkey 2.2) and Chrome 11, timeouts are clamped to firing no more often than once per second (1000ms) in inactive tabs..."*

See this [related SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032429/chrome-timeouts-interval-suspended-in-background-tabs) post for more.

Comment: And it doesn't take a callback, it takes code or a function.

Comment: Ahh, thanks for the catch j08691! And Matt, I believe there IS in fact a minimum delay (see the reference I posted).

Comment: Those saying that a delay of 0 "works" in the sense that it doesn't throw an error; sure, it does. **BUT** the 0 is being overridden by the minimum delay (see updated answer for clarification).

Comment: Probably an off-topic comment, but I would say that if a function doesn't behave as you would expect it to, then that is an error (user-error or code-error, haha). Likewise, if you assume that setting the delay to 0 is *actually* setting the timeout as low as it can go (but not 0 -- since conceptually that makes no sense), then sure I guess it isn't an error. It is important to note the distinction though: **a timeout of 0 is not actually a timeout of 0 milliseconds.**

Comment: Oh, derp. Updated to include that point. Thanks for the reminder, @Huangism.